# Factorygirl has_one association through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I have a model with a `has_one` association `through` another model.

```
class Publisher
  has_many :books
end

class Book
  belongs_to :publisher
  has_one :author
end

class Author
  belongs_to :book
  has_one :publisher, :through => :book
end
```

In my Rails code, I can call `author.publisher` without a problem, so that all works nicely. However in my specs (using Rspec and FactoryGirl, the association just doesn't seem to work. Here are my FactoryGirl definitions:

```
Factory.define :author do |a|
  a.association :book
end

Factory.define :book do |b|
  b.association :publisher
end

Factory.define :publisher
end
```

(Omitted most of the attributes from the factories).

Now in my specs, I can do the following

```
pub = Factory(:publisher)
book = Factory(:book, :publisher => pub)
author = Factory(:author, :book => book)

author.book # => Returns book
author.book.publisher # => Returns publisher 
author.publisher # => nil
```

So why doesn't my `through` association work?

Comment: What version of `factory_girl`/`factory_girl_rails` are you using? With 4.1.0 this works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `factory_girl`/`factory_girl_rails` 4.1.0, the following works for me:

**`factories.rb`**

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :author do
    book
  end

  factory :book do
    publisher
  end

  factory :publisher do
  end

end
```

In the rails console:

```
pub = FactoryGirl.create(:publisher)
#=> #<Publisher id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26">
book = FactoryGirl.create(:book, :publisher => pub)
#=> #<Book id: 1, publisher_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:23", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:23">
author = FactoryGirl.create(:author, :book => book)
#=> #<Author id: 1, book_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:57", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:57">
author.book
#=> #<Book id: 1, publisher_id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:23", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:36:23">
author.book.publisher
#=> #<Publisher id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26">
author.publisher
#=> #<Publisher id: 1, created_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26", updated_at: "2013-01-30 13:35:26">
```

Curiously, the last `author.publisher` requires an additional SELECT operation, whereas `author.book.publisher` does not (perhaps related to the `nil` you observe):

```
Publisher Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "publishers".* FROM "publishers"
  INNER JOIN "books" ON "publishers"."id" = "books"."publisher_id"
  WHERE "books"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

The same thing happens if you use `Publisher.create`, `Book.create`, `Author.create` instead of `FactoryGirl.create`, so this is not factory girl behaviour but rails behaviour, something to do with how `through` associations are cached.